# Hessian vs Tibco rv

Tags: java, networking, tibco-rv

I'm looking to contrast Tibco rv and Hessian in terms of performance - for a Java application.

Any pointer to get me started appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Since Tibco RV is a JMS implementaton, I assume you mean Hessian used for messaging as part of Resin as opposed to the Hessian binary web services protocol (http://hessian.caucho.com/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "performance".

I have had a lot of Tibco experience but no Hessian so I can only comment of the RV side of things.

RV makes very efficient (and I mean VERY efficient) use of network and server resouces, it makes extensive use of TCP/IP broadcast to avoid sending the same message to n clients. Additionally messages are not sent directly to clients but to an end point on machine which then forwards the message to any clients logged on to the machine.

Additionaly the core product is several years old and was designed to run on what was considered quite modest harware circa 1995 ( single processer 200 mhz 256MB memory SparcStation would have been typical for the server end! ) so on todays hardware it can handle a vast volume of messages while sitting twoards the bottom of the "top" list.

There are a couple of downsides (compared with say Webshpere MQ); transactional support is limited and not up to MQ or database standards plus there is no built in guarenteed delivery or "dead letter" processing, although its fairly easy to code around this in an application.

Comment: I remember doing a Tibco trial in 1991/92 time-frame on 33mhz machines.

Answer (score 1):

The places I would go to start would be:

**First** examine the underlying structure of the messaging service.

[TIBCO Rendezvous](http://www.tibco.com/software/messaging/rendezvous/default.jsp) looks like it's built directly on top of TCP/IP and has broad cross platform support.

[Hessian Messaging](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/protocols/hessian-messaging.xtp) appears to be a layer of code on top of standard RPC.  This makes it simpler and easier to maintain maybe, but also means that it's completely dependent on the RPC implementation.

**Another approach** would be to compare how many people use it and how well tested it is.

**Finally**, a good thing to do would be to see if TIBCO and Hessian provide demo versions that you can actually stress test in your own environment, to get the best idea of the performance of either in your unique setting.

Comment: Minor clarification regarding Tibco Rendezvous: I believe RV uses UDP over LAN; TCP/SSL is used for WAN communication.